# Install MongoDB on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, mongodb

How can I install MongoDB on  my Ubuntu 17.04??

Looks like there are no packages provided by Mongo at the moment, just wondering if someone has already managed to install an instance on 17.04?

Answer (score 9):

Mongo only provides packages for LTS versions, so there won't be a package for 17.04 *ever*.

That being said, you can try following the instructions for 16.04, as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), specifically:

```sh
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" |
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
```

and then update your apt cache and install mongo:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

For more info see the [official installation instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 7):

**mongoDB** didn't prepare a link for 17.04 now.
But you can install it on your machine with these commands from Ubuntu’s [Universe repository](/q/148638/175814).

### Steps

1. Enable the [Universe repository](/q/148638/175814) if you haven’t done so in the past.
2. `sudo apt update`
3. install for client:

   ```
   sudo apt install mongodb-clients
   ```

   install for server:

   ```
   sudo apt install mongodb-server
   ```

   for both:

   ```
   sudo apt install mongodb
   ```

Comment: I don't know why.but sudo apt install mongodb for me doesn't work.but when I use sudo apt install mongodb-clinets works fine

Answer (score 4):

Only 
`sudo apt install mongodb` 
commond is enough for the installation of Mongo DB. Once installation is completed execute `Mongo` commond, it will start mongo server. Default location for Data will be var/lib/mongodb

Comment: On 17.10 this installs Mongo 3.4. To get 3.6 on 17.10 do this: https://medium.com/gatemill/how-to-install-mongodb-3-6-on-ubuntu-17-10-ac0bc225e648

Answer (score 0):

The community edition from mongo is only for ubuntu 16.04, latest LTS, but mongodb 3.6. The package is mongodb-org.

The ubuntu repos have mongodb for ubuntu 17.10/artful, but only mongo db version 3.4.7, the packages are mongodb-*

So either use

- the newest monogo db, but for an older ubuntu
  or
- the older mongo db but for the newest ubuntu release.

Third option, just for completeness:
Compile it yourself... (not that hard, but still ...)

I haven't found a "backport" ("foreport" ?) yet.

Comment: To get 3.6 on 17.10 do this: https://medium.com/gatemill/how-to-install-mongodb-3-6-on-ubuntu-17-10-ac0bc225e648