# apt-get failed to install mongodb for Ubuntu 17.04 on arm platform (Odroid XU4)

Tags: apt, software-installation, 17.04, arm, mongodb

I want to precise that this is not a duplicated issue.

I've been trying to install mongodb on my odroid XU4 (raspberry like), running on Ubuntu 17.04, using the command "sudo apt-get install -y mongodb"

Here's the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate
```

Here's the output of `sudo apt-get update`

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com zesty InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com zesty-backports InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com zesty-proposed InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/random-stuff/ppa/ubuntu wily InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu wily     InRelease
Hit:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com zesty-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com zesty-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports zesty InRelease
Ign:10 http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-enterprise/3.4 InRelease
Hit:11 http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-enterprise/3.4 Release
Hit:12 https://dev2day.de/pms jessie InRelease
Ign:13 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease
Hit:14 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 Release
Reading package lists... Done
```

Here's the output of `uname -m`

```
armv7l
```

Here's the output of `dpkg --print-architecture`

```
armhf
```

Here's the output of `apt-cache policy mongodb mongodb-tools mongodb-org`

```
mongodb:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
N: Unable to locate package mongodb-tools
N: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
```

I've already done the following:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
sudo apt update
```

I also tried instruction in the following post: [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912406/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-17-04) with the following result:

```
> sudo apt install mongodb-clients
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb-clients is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mongo-tools

E: Package 'mongodb-clients' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried:

```
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
> echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-enterprise/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise.list
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-enterprise
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package mongodb-enterprise
```

And many other things found on internet, but I'm running out of ideas.. Does someone have a hint?

Thanks !

Comment: What didn't work exactly?  Please [edit] your question and provide more details...

Comment: What kind of details do you want? :) (I thought the question was clear enough.. Sorry)

Comment: Of the existing answers: what was the output of each when you tried them?

Comment: Did you enable Ubuntu’s Universe repository? Like the answer to the linked question says it contains the `mongodb` package and its dependencies. The packages directly from the Mongo developers’ repository are called `mongodb-org`*. Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update`? Thanks.

Comment: I added the output of `sudo apt-get update` I didn't find how to enable the verbose option of the 'update' parameter

Comment: When I try to enable the Ubuntu's Universe repository (with `sudo add-apt-repository universe`) I've got the following: `'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.`

Comment: I missed the part about the ARM CPU before. Could you please add the output of `uname -m`, `dpkg --print-architecture` and `apt-cache policy mongodb mongodb-tools mongodb-org`? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

**Only working for Ubuntu versions before 17.04**

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 \
>   --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
>
> echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el,s390x ] \
>   http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-enterprise/3.4
>   multiverse" \ | sudo tee
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise.list
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-enterprise

**For Ubuntu 17.04**

Try and download the following https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-arm64-ubuntu1604-3.6.1.tgz you would have to manually install this.

Comment: When I launch the mongod command I have the error: ./mongod: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Problem is you are using Ubuntu 17.04 and it doesnt seem to exist an Ubuntu package for mongodb yet. If you try with an Ubuntu version older than 17.04 it should work. For 17.04 you can try with downloading the source code as i suggested

Comment: I downloaded the code suggests but when I launch the mongod command I have the error: ./mongod: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error